# Python socket .connect() "An invalid argument was supplied" (OSError: [WinError 10022])

Tags: python, windows

While making a client from Python's socket module, I encounter`OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied`, of which I am confused by it's cause and how to manage it.

For what it's worth, I'm on Windows 10.

In brief, the target code revolves around the connection process:

```
import socket

client = socket.socket()

hostname = socket.gethostname()
port = 50007

while (True):
    client.settimeout(0.1)

    try:
        client.connect((hostname, port))

    except socket.timeout:
        print("timeout")
        continue

    else:
        . . .
```

Which returns:

```
timeout
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/testClient.py", line 12, in <module>
    client.connect((hostname, port))
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Admittedly, this error only presented itself once the timeout stuff was introduced. As shown by the output, it successfully timed out once but fails on its second retry.

I have checked the `hostName` and `port` variables after it timed out, however they no not change (as they shouldn't).

The only reason I have the system in a loop with timeout is because I am also using the tkinter module for a user interface, and I want the UI to be constantly updated so the program doesn't stop responding. All I want is for the connection to retry if it times out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `hostname`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're firing `connect()` on the **same** socket object too fast (please do not ask about the internals, but the socket is just not ready to re-connect yet).

There are at least 2 options to work around this:

#### Option 1 - sleep between attempts

```
import socket
import time

address = (socket.gethostname(), 50007)
client = socket.socket()
client.settimeout(0.1)

while (True):
    try:
        client.connect(address)
    except socket.timeout:
        print("timeout")
        time.sleep(1)
```

#### Option 2 - create a new socket for each attempt

```
import socket

address = (socket.gethostname(), 50007)

while (True):
    client = socket.socket()
    client.settimeout(0.1)
    try:
        client.connect(address)
    except socket.timeout:
        print("timeout")
```

#### Option 3 - use `connect_ex()`

```
import socket

address = (socket.gethostname(), 50007)
client = socket.socket()
client.settimeout(0.1)

while (True):
    res = client.connect_ex(address)
    if(res != 0):
        print("Error / timeout", res)
```

Though option 3 is basically the same as if you use your initial attempt and simply catch all exceptions, not just `socket.timeout`.