# Paramiko SSHClient will not connect in executable built with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, sockets, pyinstaller, paramiko

**EDIT**

The issue is fixed, but only if I run the produced executable from my desktop instead of the server location I've been developing and running from (VPN). No change to the code was necessary, but I would prefer to have something more robust. There's no reason this shouldn't work when running from a network location, especially considering it works fine if I run the script without creating the executable. It's seeming like the sluggishness that comes from running it there versus on my computer's desktop is what is somehow causing things to behave differently. I'd really like to know why that is, and if there's a way to avoid it.

---

**Versions:**

- Windows 10
- Python: 3.8.3
- PyInstaller: 3.6
- Paramiko: 2.7.1

Below is a minimal version of the code that exhibits the issue:

```
import paramiko

ip = "10.0.0.172"
username = "username"
password = "password"

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(ip, username=username, password=password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("ls")
print(stdout.readlines())

client.close()
```

I am using `pipenv` to contain these packages in a virtual environment.

When running natively (e.g. `pipenv run python main.py`), there are no problems. Running the executable produced by Pyinstaller, using `pipenv run pyinstaller Test.spec --distpath "./Release"`, results in the following runtime error when running the produced executable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
File "lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 343, in connect
File "socket.py", line 231, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

**Things I have tried:**

- Adding "_socket" and "socket" to `hiddenimports` in the .spec file
- Installing different versions of Python, Pyinstaller, Paramiko
- Searching for other people with this issue. The closest I found was [This Github Issue](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1487) which mentions "PuTTY Pageant" (Which I don't have and am not running it or anything similar). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330897/oserror-winerror-10022-an-invalid-argument-was-supplied-windows-10-python) is a StackOverflow post with the same error, but from someone who is attempting to create a `socket` themselves and appears to be running it with Python directly instead of through an executable created with Pyinstaller. And [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437148/python-socket-connect-an-invalid-argument-was-supplied-oserror-winerror) is another post that suggests having multiple attempts to create a socket, which I implemented and still ran into the issue.
- Restarting my computer and running the executable in a fresh boot state

And here is my .spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=["_socket"],
    hookspath=[],
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False
)
         
pyz = PYZ(
    a.pure,
    a.zipped_data,
    cipher=block_cipher
)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='Test',
    debug=True,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True
)

coll = COLLECT(exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='Test'
)
```

Your help is appreciated.